# pod install error: curl: (18) transfer closed with 54357829 bytes remaining to read

Tags: cocoapods

pod install, TwilioVoice update error.

```
pod install 
Analyzing dependencies  
Downloading dependencies  
Installing AFNetworking (3.2.1)  
Installing CocoaAsyncSocket (7.6.3)  
Installing CocoaLumberjack (3.5.3)  
Installing GoogleMaps (3.4.0)  
Installing GooglePlaces (3.4.0)  
Installing Masonry (1.1.0)  
Installing SDWebImage (4.4.7)  
Installing TwilioVideo (2.10.2)  
Installing TwilioVoice (5.1.2)  

[!] Error installing TwilioVoice  
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/zl/014s9t8x7n90s8thffl59zx40000gn/T/d20200728-3792-5cbjyi/file.zip https://github.com/twilio/twilio-voice-ios/releases/download/5.1.2/TwilioVoice.framework.zip --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2  

  % Total   % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current  <br>
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed  <br>
100   638  100   638    0     0    489      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   490  <br>
  3 53.6M    3 1852k    0     0   3034      0  5:09:01  0:10:25  4:58:36     0  <br>
curl: (18) transfer closed with 54357829 bytes remaining to read  <br>
```

TwilioVoice.podspec.json

```
{
  "name": "TwilioVoice",
  "version": "5.1.2",
  "summary": "Twilio Voice",
  "description": "Twilio Voice makes it easy to embed VoIP directly into your iOS apps.",
  "homepage": "http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice-sdk",
  "platforms": {
    "ios": "10.0"
  },
  "license": {
    "type": "Commercial",
    "text": "Copyright © 2011-2017 Twilio, Inc. All rights reserved. Use of this software is subject to the terms and conditions of the Twilio Terms of Service located at http://www.twilio.com/legal/tos"
  },
  "authors": {
    "Twilio": "help@twilio.com"
  },
  "source": {
    "http": "https://github.com/twilio/twilio-voice-ios/releases/download/5.1.2/TwilioVoice.framework.zip"
  },
  "documentation_url": "https://twilio.github.io/twilio-voice-ios/docs/5.1.2",
  "vendored_frameworks": "Build/iOS/TwilioVoice.framework",
  "requires_arc": true,
  "xcconfig": {
    "OTHER_LDFLAGS": "-ObjC"
  }
}
```

I can open and download the zip in Chroom with https://github.com/twilio/twilio-voice-ios/releases/download/5.1.2/TwilioVoice.framework.zip. But not install with the pod. Why? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue has done. Close the Proxifier and then pod install.